# In Illustrator can I prevent a calligraphy brush stroke from changing when rotated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, calligraphy

In Illustrator, using a calligraphy brush with a ~45 degree angle, I drew a path that looks good in my illustration.

Now I would like to rotate that path to use it in a different orientation, but exactly as it looks now.

When I do this rotation, though, the stroke changes due to it being a Calligraphy brush.

Is there a way to 'disconnect' or 'freeze' the calligraphy aspect so the stroke can be rotated without changing?

Comment: Whats wrong with expandibg the stroke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Select the stroke and choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu if it is available.

Depending upon specific needs you may *also* want to chose `Object > Expand`.

These "bake in" appearance aspects.

---

You can also leave things as they are, rotate your stroke, then adjust the brush preferences to un-rotate the calligraphic stroke.

Basically you would need to rotate the stroke, then adjust the calligraphy to compensate for your rotation. With live brush strokes, you can't rotate the stroke without also rotating the calligraphic aspect.

Comment: You can also expand as a effect and rotate with transform effect but tahts a bit clunky.